# How to investigate invalid image data in Paw

Tags: paw-app

When viewing a request for an image, the message Invalid image data is given in the response panel under the Image option. The headers section shows the Content-Type as image/jpeg.

Is there a chance that Paw is failing to render the image? Is there any option to download the image?

Comment: sorry for the late answer. It's a bug currently in Paw 2.2.2, we are working on it and will be fixed in the next bugfix version for Paw.

Answer (score 3):

I can't seem to get Paw to render an image either. You can save the image in the response body with File - Export - Response Body. Whenever I do this, Preview is able to view the exported image without a problem.